# Windows Command Prompt auto-completion with forward slashes?

Tags: windows-7, linux, command-line, autocomplete

I switch between Linux and Windows quite a lot and it's annoying the hell out of me that the Windows command prompt won't auto-complete directory paths when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> if I use forward slashes like in Linux.

For example, if I'm trying to navigate to a directory 'bin':

`cd /path/to/dir/b <tab>` - this won't auto-complete to 'bin'

`cd \path\to\dir\b <tab>` - this will auto-complete.

Can I tell the Command Prompt to use forward slashes instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is no. The longer better answer is that since you are on Windows 7, you should move to using powershell instead of cmd which will autocomplete using /.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I didn't realise Windows 7 came with Powershell!

Comment: It's the best part of Windows 7 :)

Comment: powershell has its own drawback... May be it's in Beta mode... in future version of windows people may expect it to be fixed. :)

Comment: It is not in beta. All languages/shells have issues.